# Second derivative of $y(t) = \frac{t \cdot \cos(t)}{\sinh(t^2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've given the following function: $y: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $y(t) = \frac{t \cdot \cos(t)}{\sinh(t^2)}$

My task is to calculate the first and the second derivative of $y$.

I've already calculated the first derivative: $$y'(t) = \frac{y(t)}{t} - \frac{t \cdot \sin(t)}{\sinh(t^2)} - y(t) \cdot 2 \cdot t \cdot \coth(t^2)$$

Wolfram Alpha told me, that this is correct, but there has to be a nice simplification...

$\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{y(t)}{t} \right)$ and $\frac{d}{dt} \left(y(t) \cdot 2 \cdot t \cdot \coth(t^2) \right)$ is no problem, but I really don't want to calculate $\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{t \cdot \sin(t)}{\sinh(t^2)} \right)$ for the second derivative...

Any hints, maybe?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

You can write the first derivative as

$$y'(t)=y(t)\left(\frac1t -\tan (t)-2t\,\coth (t^2)\right)$$

Then, the second derivative is

$$y''(t)=y'(t)\left(\frac1t -\tan (t)-2t\,\coth (t^2)\right)+y(t)\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac1t -\tan (t)-2t\,\coth (t^2)\right)$$

That is quite tractable.  Can you finish?